# Wait for AJAX requests inside a $.each using $.Deferred

Tags: jquery, ajax, deferred

I have a $.each cycle that fires an AJAX request.
What I want to do is wait until all AJAX requests are completed. I don't mind about the result of those AJAX requests, the matter is that I must be sure they are finished.
I think this can be done using $.Deferred, but I can't figure out how, even after have read the JQuery documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wait for all AJAX requests to finish you can store the `jqXHR` objects returned from the calls in an array. Then you can apply that array to `$.when` to be run when all request finish. Try this:

```
var requests = yourDataStructure.map(function() {
  return $.ajax({
    // setup...
  });
});

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
  console.log('All requests finished, do something here...');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.when(request1(), request2(), ... ,requestn()).done(function(res1, res2, ... , resn){
    // what to do when I get all the response / when it finished
});
```

I used to found this answer on the stack overflow and if I can find the link I will put the link below.

NB: dont give me a vote I just want to help & I only referred this from somewhere in the stack overflow. I will put the link when I found it :)

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, since I have a foreach loop and I can't know how many requestX() functions I'll need.